# jQuery animate - opacity slower than height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Wondering if it's possible to make a jQuery animate property slower than another - here's what I have right now:

```
    $(".thebox").animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    },250);
```

When `.thebox` fades in and slides down simultaneously, I'd like to make opacity part of the animation slower, while making the height part faster.

The whole thing has to work with a button that on `click` causes the animation. It must be a toggle switch.

Thanks to anyone able to answer this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack the animations on top of each other, and disable the default animation queueing.

```
$(".thebox")
.animate({height: "toggle"}, {duration: 250, queue:false})
.animate({opacity: "toggle"}, {duration: 500, queue:false});  // Runs twice as slow.
```

**EDIT:**

Since the events are triggered twice using toggle, we need a different approach, to detect wheter to hide or show the box. One simple solution would be a helper-class as such:

```
var theBox = $('.thebox');
if (theBox.hasClass('active')) {
    // It is active, then fade it out
    thebox
    .removeClass('active')
    .animate({height: 0}, {duration: 250, queue:false})
    .animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 500, queue:false});

} else {
    // It is not active, show it
    thebox
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({height: 'auto'}, {duration: 250, queue:false})
    .animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 500, queue:false});
}
```

Worth pointing out: The animations can be done using slideUp, slideDown, fadeIn and fadeOut instead of animate(). Also note the above assumes that there is only one element with the class `theBox`.

Comment: Great! Then I'd appreciate a nice little green check on this answer! :-)

Comment: @Eric: He can't accept the answer for another 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't actually work. .thebox animates out again directly after the toggle is pressed.

Comment: @SnowLeopard: I think it's because there are two `toggle`s. I would suggest detecting beforehand whether you want to show or hide and then explicitly saying `"show"` or `"hide"` with the animations. http://jsbin.com/avujil/1 (http://jsbin.com/avujil/1/edit). The fundamental thing is the `queue` option that Eric pointed out.

Comment: Interesting. I believe this has to do with the `toggle` option; they gets triggered twice since they are stacked. You can avoid this by keeping track of which state the box is in, by maybe adding a class `active` etc. Then either show or hide, depending on if the box has the class or not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder will that work with a button that will toggle the display of the div? I can't have two buttons for each action.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your suggestion, it worked. I'll give you a green tick now. :)

Comment: @jmd: I didn't mean separate buttons, I meant what Eric said later. Glad it's sorted out now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True, check it out.

Comment: @Eric: Cool. I took the liberty of a small change, but I think anyone finding this will be well served, nice answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Now days with the NSA and CIA on our lines, the liberty is worth a discussion, lol. May your code in the future however, strike with might and faith.